# Debezium - Update Operation Emits Change Event into Kafka Topic with Both Before & After Struct Values ,But Ignores null Column/Field in Before Struct

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, change-data-capture

I'm using debezium to synchronize the data between two postgres DB server & i'm facing an issue with the **update event/operation** as it's recording the change event into kafka topic by **ignoring the null value column/field**(refer below *infodetcode* field missing in the before struct as it was null in DB ), same column/field is avail in after struct as the value changed from "null" to "some value", with the null value column missing in before struct, when i compare before with after struct to find out which are the field/column values are unique/duplicate to construct dynamic query,query is constructed with the missing column,and it is necessary to put that column in the query(please find the below configuration & comparison implementation of before and after struct which returns result without null value column),I'd gladly take suggestions/help on this issue.

**Note : REPLICA IDENTITY is set to "FULL"**

**Version:**
PostgreSQL  - 10.9, debezium - 1.1.1.Final

**Before & After Struct-Topic Record(Actual)**:

```
    before=struct{accountno=01,currencycode=USD,seqno=1,informationcode=S}
    after=struct{accountno=01,currencycode=USD,seqno=1   ,informationcode=M  ,infodetcode=N}
```

**Before & After Struct-Topic Record(Expected)**:

```
 before=struct{accountno=01,currencycode=USD,seqno=1,informationcode=S,infodetcode=null}
            after=struct{accountno=01,currencycode=USD,seqno=1   ,informationcode=M  ,infodetcode=N}
```

**Debezium configuration:**

```
@Bean
public io.debezium.config.Configuration postgreConnectorConfiguration() {
    return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
            .with("name", "postgres-connector")
            .with("snapshot.mode", SnapshotMode.CUSTOM)
            .with("snapshot.custom.class", "postgresql.snapshot.CustomSnapshotter")
            .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector")
            .with("database.history", "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory")
            .with("database.history.file.filename", "/debezium/dbhistory.dat")
            .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
            .with("offset.storage.file.filename", "/debezium/offset/postgre-offset.dat")
            .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", 60000)
            .with("snapshot.isolation.mode", "read_committed")
            .with("key.converter.schemas.enable",true)
            .with("value.converter.schemas.enable", true)

            .with("plugin.name", "pgoutput")
            .with("slot.name", "debeziumtest")
            .with("database.server.name", "server-c")
            .with("database.hostname", databaseHost)
            .with("database.port", databasePort)
            .with("database.user", databaseUserName)
            .with("database.password", databasePassword)
            .with("database.dbname", databaseName)
            .with("table.whitelist", TABLES_TO_MONITOR).build();
}
```

**Comparison of Struct(Before & After):**

```
private void handleEvent(SourceRecord sourceRecord) {
    Struct sourceRecordEntry = (Struct) sourceRecord.value();

    if (sourceRecordEntry != null) {

        Struct sourceStruct = (Struct) sourceRecordEntry.get(FieldName.SOURCE);

        String tableName =  sourceStruct.getString(TABLE);
        Date transactionDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Long transctionTime = (Long) sourceStruct.get(FieldName.TIMESTAMP);
        Time txnTime = new Time(transctionTime);
        Long transactionCode = (Long) sourceStruct.get(TRANSACTION_ID);
        Operation operation = Operation.forCode(sourceRecordEntry.getString(OPERATION));

    if (operation == Operation.UPDATE) {

            Map<String, Object> beforeEntryHash;
            Map<String, Object> afterEntryHash;

            List preFieldList = new ArrayList();
            List preValueList = new ArrayList();
            List postFieldList = new ArrayList();
            List postValueList = new ArrayList();
            Integer preFieldcount = 0, preValuecount = 0, postFieldcount = 0, postValuecount = 0;

            Struct beforeStruct = (Struct) sourceRecordEntry.get(BEFORE);
            Struct afterStruct = (Struct) sourceRecordEntry.get(AFTER);

            beforeEntryHash = beforeStruct.schema().fields().stream().map(Field::name).filter(fieldName->beforeStruct.get(fieldName)!=null).map(fieldName-> Pair.of(fieldName, beforeStruct.get(fieldName))).collect(toMap(Pair::getKey,Pair::getValue));
            afterEntryHash = afterStruct.schema().fields().stream().map(Field::name).filter(fieldName->afterStruct.get(fieldName)!=null).map(fieldName-> Pair.of(fieldName, afterStruct.get(fieldName))).collect(toMap(Pair::getKey,Pair::getValue));

            MapDifference<String, Object> rowDifferenceHash  = Maps.difference(beforeEntryHash, afterEntryHash);

            for(Entry<String, ValueDifference<Object>> rowEntry : rowDifferenceHash.entriesDiffering().entrySet()) {
                preFieldList.add(PR_PREFIX + rowEntry.getKey());
                postFieldList.add(PO_PREFIX + rowEntry.getKey());
                preValueList.add(SQ + rowEntry.getValue().leftValue() + SQ);
                postValueList.add(SQ + rowEntry.getValue().rightValue() + SQ);
                LOGGER.info("Key : "  + rowEntry.getKey() + " Left Value : " + rowEntry.getValue().leftValue() + " Right Value : " + rowEntry.getValue().rightValue());

              }
        }
    }
}
```

**Message**:

```
SourceRecord{sourcePartition={server=server-c}, sourceOffset={transaction_id=null, lsn_proc=4921004793408, lsn=4921004793408, txId=81939856, ts_usec=1588212060567019}} ConnectRecord{topic='server-c.a.accinfo', kafkaPartition=null, key=Struct{accountno=01           ,currencycode=USD,seqno=1   }, keySchema=Schema{server-c.a.accinfo.Key:STRUCT}, value=Struct{before=Struct{accountno=01           ,currencycode=USD,seqno=1   ,informationcode=S  },after=Struct{accountno=01           ,currencycode=USD,seqno=1   ,informationcode=P  ,infodetcode=I},source=Struct{version=1.2.0.Alpha1,connector=postgresql,name=server-c,ts_ms=1588212060567,db=OTATEMP,schema=a,table=accinfo,txId=81939856,lsn=4921004793408},op=u,ts_ms=1588213782961}, valueSchema=Schema{server-c.a.accinfo.Envelope:STRUCT}, timestamp=null, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}
```

**Schema:**

```
[Field{name=before, index=0, schema=Schema{server-c.aeota.accinfo.Value:STRUCT}}, Field{name=after, index=1, schema=Schema{server-c.aeota.accinfo.Value:STRUCT}}, Field{name=source, index=2, schema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source:STRUCT}}, Field{name=op, index=3, schema=Schema{STRING}}, Field{name=ts_ms, index=4, schema=Schema{INT64}}, Field{name=transaction, index=5, schema=Schema{STRUCT}}]
```

Comment: Hi, could you please look into the message schema? Is the missing column in the schema? If yes is the default value set to `null`?

Comment: Hi Jiri Pechanec, Above I have added the entire message that received, it's not having the missing column.

Comment: Hi, you've passed the content of the message but I am interested in schema. If schema contains the column and default value is null then it works as expected as `Struct.getXXX` method will correctly provide the `null` value.

Comment: Hi, Even in the message schema,not even one column name is appended to the topic(please refer above attached schema category),do i need to enable something to make the schema values append to topic?or is it a problem with pgoutput decoder plug-in?

Comment: Could you please try another decoder plugin? I wonder if this is specific to pgoutput or not.